# Functions that behave like subgradients of a convex potential

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am interested in functions $\phi:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ with the following property. For all $x,y\in\mathbb R^d, (\phi(x)-\phi(y))^\top (x-y)\geq 0$.

For instance, if $\phi$ is the gradient (or a subgradients) of a convex function, it satisfies this property, but this property is more general.

Examples of such functions include functions of the form $\phi=f+g$ where $f$ is a subgradients of an $\alpha$-strongly convex function and $g$ is any Lipschitz function with Lipschitz constant at most $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ could be any positive number. Other examples are given by $x\mapsto Ax$ where $A$ is any $d\times d$ matrix such that $A+A^\top$ is positive semi-definite.

First, is the set of zeros necessarily convex (or empty)? Note that if the monotonicity condition that defines such a function (see above) is a strict inequality whenever $x\neq y$, then the set of zeros is either empty or a singleton.
Second, are there non-trivial properties satisfied by such functions? For instance, are they always continuous everywhere outside an at most countable subset? Can they always be decomposed as the sum of a subgradient of a convex function and a simple function (in any possible sense)?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "is the set of zeros necessarily convex (or empty)?". Moreover, I feel like your questions are too vague (e.g. "are there non-trivial properties satisfied by such functions?"). I would suggest rephrasing your question by asking something more specific.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.
"is the set of zeros necessarily convex (or empty)?" = Is the set $\{x\in\mathbb R^d:\phi(x)=0\}$ necessarily a (possibly empty) convex set?